# Do ASP.Net controls expose SQL Queries via viewstate?

Tags: asp.net, security, sql-injection, viewstate

Do controls, that are part of the default ASP.Net control set - ALL use viewstate or controlstate all the time?

i.e. If I drop the code below onto a brand new web form, is my SQL string placed in unencrypted controlstate?

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="mobileData" runat="server" 
        DataSourceMode="DataReader" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * from ma.bob WHERE Vendor IS NOT NULL" 
/>
```

I'm aware of how to encrypt viewstate and controlstate, but it seems crazy to me that this common use case could be so horrendously insecure. Surely one could perform a SQL injection attack by modifying the controlstate?

I think most people think of encrypting controlstate for sensitive applications, but actually, if my assumption is true - then it should always be done - and visual studio should enable it by default?

Am I thinking about this correctly, or do I have the wrong end of the stick?

Comment: You might want to review: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/115374/using-sqldatasource-databound-controls-in-asp-net-bad-practice

Comment: Why would that string go into ViewState or ControlState? It's static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, **no**.
From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.selectcommand.aspx)

> For security purposes, the SelectCommand property is not stored is view state. Because it is possible to decode the contents of view
>   state on the client, storing sensitive information about the database
>   structure in view state could result in an information disclosure
>   vulnerability.

Answer (score 1):

This info is never stored in the ViewState.


Not all properties are created like this

```
public string SomeProperty
        {
            get
            {
                object obj = ViewState["SomeProperty"];
                return (obj == null) ? 0 : (string)obj;
            }
            set
            {
                ViewState["SomeProperty"] = value;
            }
        }
```

**SelectCommand** here is assigned in a generated C#/Vb class by the PageParser. That class will contain some line like

```
 mobileData.SelectCommand="SELECT * from ma.bob WHERE Vendor IS NOT NULL"
```

and this assignment is made every time the page is requested. There is no need for ASP .Net to keep this in ViewState.

However if you do something like

```
  <asp:HiddenField runat="server" Value="SELECT * from ma.bob WHERE Vendor IS NOT NULL" />
```

This will go the ViewState (what I said about the parser is true here also, but the setter implements here that ViewState mechanism)

Comment: Do you have an authoritative source that states this?